# civirules extension -- send an email, SMS or PDF actions not available

Tags: civirules

I've installed the CiviRules extension but I am missing some actions that I thought to be built in.  Send an email, SMS or PDF actions are not available.

Linked Trigger: Address is changed
Linked Conditions: None[image]

See screenshot.

Drupal version - 7.41
CiviCRM - 4.6.10
CiviRules - 1.1

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Those come in separate extensions. You'll need to install these:

- https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/smsapi / https://civicrm.org/extensions/sms-api
- https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/pdfapi / https://civicrm.org/extensions/pdf-creation-api
- https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/emailapi / https://civicrm.org/extensions/e-mail-api

Comment: wanna update with gitlab links eg https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/emailapi

Comment: @petednz-fuzion - Looks like that and https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/pdfapi - couldn't find one for SMS API. I am however no longer involved and can't promise other stuff hasn't changed.

Answer (score 3):

As DaveFF mentioned, they are separate extension that enable the Email, PDF and SMS API's. Part of those extensions is to add CiviRules actions if it finds out you have CiviRules enabled in your installation.