# How do notifications for recurring payments work?

Tags: recurring-contributions

I've got a site that has had recurring payments (via paypal) working for some time, but only recently had the ipn settings configured correctly. Now that that is working we're getting more notifications than anticipated, so I just want to check my understanding on what's happening.

Memberships were set up to cc an info@ address in to the membership reciept. And also when the "member details" profile in the contribution page was submitted.

This now works as expected for new membership subscriptions.

The unexpected side is that the membership admins are getting the same notifications for the automated renewals. They are cc'd into membership renewal receipt, and it looks like the recurring payment resubmits the profile data so they're getting a notification from that as well.

I've not had much dealing with recurring payments before, I just want to check that this is the expected behaviour.

In which case. cc into reciept and notify from profile submission from the membership contribution page are the wrong way to notify membership admin about new members. I'm guessing a scheduled reminder for member join, limited to the admin email only would be a better way to go.

Also the contribution page that created the membership has been updated several times over the years so it now is no longer a membership page, and uses different profiles. So the notifications are linked to the original payment record and changing the contribution page makes not a blind bit of difference to associated recurring payments.

Removing the submission notification address on the profile will stop future notification emails (I guess). But I can't see a way to stop the cc notification from each membership renewal reciept, at least in the civi user interface- can this be amended from the sql tables?

So two questions
1) Is civi behaving as it should, and our expectations of the original set up was wrong?
2) How can I kill off future notifications for recurring payments

----editting after further work----
Scheduled reminders don't function as I thought, and can't add a cc to a scheduled reminder. So can't send a "welcome to us" message and cc the admin address in.

Looked at Civi Rules on the demo site- can set a trigger for membership added. But, "Send email to..." not available as an action.

Answer (score 2):

There is an answer [here](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/8082/96) that says among other things

You'll need to install these:

https://github.com/CiviCooP/org.civicoop.emailapi / https://civicrm.org/extensions/e-mail-api

Comment: Thanks Pete,

Installing and testing now.